# Разрыв последовательности в Sequence Generator во время rollback transaction при работе в Oracle и Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Я использую

- Spring boot 2.x
- Spring Data Jpa
- Hibernate
- Oracle 11.x

```java
...
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "jpaSequence.Company",
            sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_COMPANY",
            allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jpaSequence.Company")
private Long id;

...
```

- Sequence generator:

Increment: 1

Min value: 1

Cache: no cache

Cycle: no cycle

Order: Order

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQUENCE_COMPANY INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 NOCACHE ORDER;
```

В случае, когда приосходит откат транзакции, то ранее выделенный id, не будет использован при следующей валидной вставке строки в базу данных.

Таким образом, получаются строки, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8 ....

Я также пробовал вот такой подход:

```java
...
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "jpaSequence",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = SequenceStyleGenerator.SEQUENCE_PARAM, value = "SEQUENCE_COMPANY"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INITIAL_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1")
            }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "jpaSequence")
    private Long id;
...
```

Также разрыв строк, но кроме того заметил, что строка с порядковым номером 4, может стоять первой в строке таблицы ???

Из документации Oracle:

> Когда порядковый номер последовательности генерируется, тогда последовательность увеличивается, независимо от фиксации транзакции или отката транзакции. Если 2 пользователя параллельно увеличивают одну и ту же последовательность, тогда порядковые номера последовательности, что приобретает каждый пользователь, могут иметь пропуски, потому что порядковые номера последовательности генерируются другим пользователем.

Как это исправить ?

Comment: а зачем исправлять? это сделано для того, чтобы точно гарантировать тебе seq

Comment: исправить порядковый номер можно только на уровне кода, не вызывать save, пока не будет уверенности в том, что транзакция сохранится. Т.е. бросать ошибку до сохранения сущности. По второму вопросу что строка с номер 4 стоит первой в таблице, select без order by не гарантирует порядок возвращенных строк (читал в доке к бд, не oracle, но думаю к нему тоже применимо)

Comment: Я использую Spring Data Jpa. Как же я должен управлять этим ? У меня указано, что в сущости должны валидироватся некоторые поля на уникальность.  Когда сохраняется строка, генератор уже отдал очередной порядковый номер, и когда строка пытается сохраниться, только тогда база отдает исключение, которое должно придти на  уровень абстракции JDBC, поверх которого работает Hibernate . Но порядковый номер то уже выдан, когда нужна была вставка строки... Во время отката транзакции, в Sequence-генераторе не происходит откат.

Comment: Если бы Hibernate (Hibernate реализует JPA, которая находится поверх JDBC ) или же более высокий дополнительный уровень абстаркции - Spring Data JPA (который является надстройкой над JPA), сначала выполнили Select, на предмет поиска дубликатов уникальных столбцов, тогда можно предположить, что  запрос на сохранение не был бы совершен. Но такой механизм должен быть реализован в Spring Data Jpa или hibernate. Но я об этом ничего не знаю.

Comment: [пример кастомного валидатора](https://emrpms.blogspot.com/2012/08/hibernate-validator-creating-custom.html) этот валидатор будет вызывать сам hibernate. Если валидация будет написана отдельным вызовом в сервисе, то это тоже нормальное поведение. В дефолтном уровне изоляции транзакций БД нет гарантий, что не будет выскакивать ошибка по constraint, и приложению должно быть без разницы какой ИД, лишь бы был уникальным.

Comment: А методы, которые пишут в базу помечены аннотациями @Transactional?

Comment: да, она установлена на уровне Service

Answer (score 3):

> Таким образом, получаются строки, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8 ... Как это исправить ?

Это не надо исправлять.

1. Последовательности гарантируют уникальность выделенныx значений в мультипользовательской среде.
2. Значения выделенные последовательностью могут иметь пропуски, именно затем, чтобы обеспечить уникальность в пункте 1.
3. Попытки избежать пропусков для порядковых номеров другими решениями, отличными от последовательностей, например с `max(id)+1`, приведут к тому, что эти решения либо не обеспечат уникальности, либо будут крайне неэффективны в мультипользовательской среде.
4. Порядковый номер записи без пропусков можно получить псевдоколонкой `ROWNUM`, но это порядковый номер записи в наборе результата запроса, а не в таблице.

> кроме того заметил, что строка с порядковым номером 4, может стоять первой в строке  таблицы (*ред.авт.: первой строкой в таблицe*)???

1. В SQL отсутствует понятие первая или последня строка в таблице. Порядка записей в таблице, связанного со значениями в какой-либо колонке, не существует.
2. Порядок записей в наборе результата запроса гарантируется только с `ORDER BY`. И только в самом внешнем подзапросе, если полный запрос состоит из подзапросов.